# Increase or Decrease field using upvote and downvote buttons

Tags: php

Novice to php / mysql:
I have a table with 2 fields (id, rating). I want to create a form with 2 buttons (upvote, downvote) that essentially update the 'rating' field of the selected id (selected at random).

Here is what I have been trying to make:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="upvote" type="image" src="up.png"id="rateup" value="upvote" />
<input name="downvote" type="image" src="down.png"id="ratedown" value="downvote" />
</form>
<?php
mysql_connect("-","-","-")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("-")or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['rateup']))
{
    $sql("UPDATE utube SET rating = rating + 1 WHERE id = '$saved_row[id]'");
}
if(isset($_POST['ratedown']))
{
    $sql("UPDATE utube SET rating = rating - 1 WHERE id = '$saved_row[id]'");
}
?>
```

I am sure I am going disastrously wrong in places, I just can't find a suitable guide to doing something like this. All and any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check the [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) function

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE utube SET rating = rating + 1 WHERE id = '$saved_row[id]'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE utube SET rating = rating + 1 WHERE id = '{$saved_row[id]}'");
```